# Need help in applying the Special Comparison Test.

Tags: analysis

**Definition**:

> [image]

Now consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^p\sin(x^q)\text{dx}$$ We have to show that the integral converges when $-1<(p+1)/q<0$.

Applying the test we observe that $f(x)$ is defined on the interval $[0,\infty)$. I am finding difficulty in applying the test as $1/(b-x)=1/(\infty-x)$ which isa meaningless quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $q>0$ and setting $\kappa=\frac{p+1}{q}$, through the substitution $x=z^{1/q}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^p\sin(x^q)\,dx = \frac{1}{q}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{\kappa-1}\sin(z)\,dz.\tag{1} $$
In order that $z^{\kappa-1}\sin(z)$ is integrable in a right neighborhood of the origin, we must have $\kappa>-1$, since in a right neighbourhood of the origin $z^{\kappa-1}\sin(z)\sim z^\kappa$. Integrability (in the Riemann sense) in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ is granted by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) as soon as $\kappa<1$. Assuming now $\color{red}{\kappa\in(-1,1)}$, we may exploit the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) to compute the RHS of $(1)$. We have:
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin z) = \frac{1}{1+s^2},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}(z^{\kappa-1})=\frac{1}{s^k\cdot \Gamma(1-k)}\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{N}z^{\kappa-1}\sin(z)\,dz = \color{red}{\Gamma(\kappa)\sin\left(\frac{\pi\kappa}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$
by the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the $\Gamma$ function.